# Poisson distribution fractional uncertainty

Tags: poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

I've been asked a question of 2 parts, the first part is easy asking when the Poisson distribution acts like a Binomial distribution.

The second part is what is messing me up. It asks: what's the uncertainty in a counting experiment with n counts. Plot the fractional uncertainty vs n counts so that I get a linear graph. I'm given the uncertainties of (10%, 5%, 1%).

My issue is that I know that fractional uncertainty (says in my notes) $1/\sqrt{n}$ so when I plug in my values for my fractional uncertainty (.1, .05, .01) I get the values of n for 100, 400, 10,000. When this is plotted it is not even close to being linear.

Where am I going wrong with my thinking?

Comment: What do you mean by "fractional uncertainty"?  What do you mean by "a counting experiment with $n$ counts"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes, n counts

Comment: I did not ask a "yes or no" question, I asked for an explanation of what you meant.  This is not standard terminology.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, sorry. That is where my confusion lies that is the exact format of the question.

Comment: I interpret your question as the uncertainty relation if you have a Poisson distributed variable N(t) and you want to compute the uncertainty in ΔN(Δt) provided dN/dt converges for large dN and dt, right?